# How to vertically combine specific columns of a sheet, while producing a category column to each dataset/range appended?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm pretty sure that this is possible with a formula, but I don't know which way to take:
`=ARRAYFORMULA()`, `=UNIQUE()`, `=QUERY()` or `=TRANSPOSE()`?

Something like: `=QUERY({A4:B9;C4:D9},"select * where Col1 is not null")`, but how can I produce column Category?

This is the scenario:

[image]

[Here's a demo file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing)

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
={{INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A4:A11))&"A","\d+",""));
   INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C4:C11))&"B","\d+",""))},
   QUERY({A4:B11;C4:D11}," select * where Col1 is not null ")}
```

[image]

One could also use the following part for the category

```
TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("A,",COUNTA(A4:A11)),",",1,1))
```

Comment: Nice. Friendly suggestion to make dynamic with no ending row... so `={{INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A4:A))&"A","\d+",""));
   INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C4:C))&"B","\d+",""))},
   QUERY({A4:B;C4:D}," select * where Col1 is not null ")}`

Comment: @pgSystemTester Sure. Also check the edited answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY({QUERY(A4:B, "select 'A',A,B"); 
        QUERY(C4:D, "select 'B',C,D")}, 
 "where Col2 is not null", )
```

[image]